# sql insert operation in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for insert operation.I tried the following but it gives me error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SetStaffSalary
    @staffid int =0,
    @amount int = 0

AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON 

BEGIN
  begin
    insert into AccStaff (totalSalary) values (@amount) where fk_staffID = @staffid;
  end
END
```

gives error `incorrect syntax near the keyword where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no "where" on insert syntax. 
example :

```
insert into account (staffid, salary) values (@id, @salary);
```

or you could use update syntax to update the data.

```
update account set salary = @salary where staffid = @id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this - it looks like you want t do update

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE setstaffsalary @staffid int = 0 , 
                               @amount int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE accstaff
    SET totalsalary = @amount
      WHERE fk_staffid
            = 
            @staffid;
END;
```